# Instabug setStringToKey get default string values

Tags: react-native, instabug

I need to add some localization to the application I am working on, and since Instabug does not support the locale in question, I plan on writing my own translations.

Instabug does provide the function [setStringToKey](https://docs.instabug.com/docs/react-native-locale#section-overriding-string-values), however I have not been able to find a reliable way to find the default *English* strings for the given keys (shakeHint, edgeSwipeStartHint etc) to make sure I am translating them properly.

I have scoured through a local clone of the [repository](https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-React-Native), searching for both the keys and values I know from use, but I haven't been able to find one place that definitively holds them, just some metadata from building.

Is there a definitive way to get the current values for all of the change-able string to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

After extensive Google-ing; and searching though every commit in the repository history to find the inclusion of a particular language I have found the following:

The strings are located in `Localization.strings` files (`.plist` encoding), in the `/ios/Instabug.framework` folder.